# Initializing, adding to, saving a local variable within a function, and accessing that variable with the function

Tags: javascript

```js
var jFunc = function() {

    var q;
    var p = 0;

    q = (typeof(q) === "undefined") ? 0 : q;

    p += 1;
    q += p; 

    console.log(q);

};
```

In the console of chrome developer tools, the output of `console.log(q)` is `q + 1` (1, 2, 3, 4, and so on..) every subsequent iteration of running the entire block of code within `jFunc` independently of invoking `jFunc`. However, when invoking `jFunc` (so as to conveniently avoid copying and pasting the code block within the console), the output is always `1` everytime. Why is this the case?

The goal is to essentially save a numeric value to a variable, add 1 to it, and return it without the use of global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a function with its own persistent scope to keep track of the counter. You can use an IIFE while defining `jFunc`:

```js
const jFunc = (() => {
  let p = 0;
  return () => {
    p++;
    return p;
  }
})();
console.log(jFunc());
console.log(jFunc());
console.log(jFunc());
```

This can be simplified a bit by just returning the `++`, but it's a bit more confusing if you're not familiar with it:

```js
const jFunc = (() => {
  let p = 0;
  return () => ++p;
})();
console.log(jFunc());
console.log(jFunc());
console.log(jFunc());
```

Or, if you need to create multiple counter functions, instead define a *higher-order function* that can *create* a counting function when called:

```js
const makeJFunc = () => {
  let p = 0;
  return () => {
    p++;
    return p;
  }
};
const jFunc1 = makeJFunc();
const jFunc2 = makeJFunc();
console.log(jFunc1());
console.log(jFunc1());
console.log(jFunc2());
console.log(jFunc1());
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for [Closures](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)

You have to return your repeating functionality as a function so that only that part can be invoked. Rest will be declared only once and will be local to that function scope.

```js
    var jFunc = (function() {
        var q;
        var p = 0;
        return function(){
        q = (typeof(q) === "undefined") ? 0 : q;
        p += 1;
        q += p; 
        console.log('q',q);
        return q;
        }
    })();
    
    jFunc();
    jFunc();
    jFunc();
```